# If radio button with value of female is checked show class female and hide class male

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can someone please help? I have 2 radio buttons. I would like to hide the dropdown menu with the class "male" if the female option and show the dropdown menu with the class of female and do the opposite if the male value is selected.
Here is what I tried:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
   if( $('input[value=Female]').is('checked') ) {
     $('.female').show();
    $('.male').hide();
   } else if( $('input[value=Male]').is('checked') ) {
    $('.male').show();
    $('.female').hide();
   } else {
     $('.male').hide();
    $('.female').hide();
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li class="input-container">
<input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_1" value="Female" type="radio">
<label for="3151_55396_8_60103_1">Female</label>
</li>
<li class="input-container">
<input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_2" value="Male" type="radio">
<label for="3151_55396_8_60103_2">Male</label>
</li>
</ul>

<select class="female" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Female - Small">Female - Small</option>
<option value="Female - Medium">Female - Medium</option>
<option value="Female - Large">Female - Large</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="male" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Male - Small">Male - Small</option>
<option value="Male - Medium">Male - Medium</option>
<option value="Male - Large">Male - Large</option>
</select>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is because you're using `checked`, not `:checked` in the `is()` method call. Also note that to follow best practices you should use the `change` event when dealing with radio and checkboxes so that users who navigate via the keyboard can still select the elements.

With that said, you can shorten the logic by using the `toggle()` method on the `select` elements, individually checking the value of the checked radio button. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.testtesttest').change(function() {
    $('.female').toggle(this.value == 'Female');
    $('.male').toggle(this.value == 'Male');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="input-container">
    <input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_1" value="Female" type="radio">
    <label for="3151_55396_8_60103_1">Female</label>
  </li>
  <li class="input-container">
    <input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_2" value="Male" type="radio">
    <label for="3151_55396_8_60103_2">Male</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<select class="female" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">
  <option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
  <option value="Female - Small">Female - Small</option>
  <option value="Female - Medium">Female - Medium</option>
  <option value="Female - Large">Female - Large</option>
</select><br />

<select class="male" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">
  <option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
  <option value="Male - Small">Male - Small</option>
  <option value="Male - Medium">Male - Medium</option>
  <option value="Male - Large">Male - Large</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

`checked` is a psedo selector and should be [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
   if( $('input[value=Female]').is(':checked') ) {
     $('.female').show();
    $('.male').hide();
   } else if( $('input[value=Male]').is(':checked') ) {
    $('.male').show();
    $('.female').hide();
   } else {
     $('.male').hide();
    $('.female').hide();
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li class="input-container">
<input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_1" value="Female" type="radio">
<label for="3151_55396_8_60103_1">Female</label>
</li>
<li class="input-container">
<input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_2" value="Male" type="radio">
<label for="3151_55396_8_60103_2">Male</label>
</li>
</ul>

<select class="female" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Female - Small">Female - Small</option>
<option value="Female - Medium">Female - Medium</option>
<option value="Female - Large">Female - Large</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="male" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Male - Small">Male - Small</option>
<option value="Male - Medium">Male - Medium</option>
<option value="Male - Large">Male - Large</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`checked` is a pseudo selector and it should be used like `:checked`. I suggest you to use `change` for the radio button. You can use that or you can get the current value using `$(this).val()` and hide the elements based on that. Please see the working snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value == 'Female') {
      $('.female').show();
      $('.male').hide();
    } else if (value == 'Male') {
      $('.male').show();
      $('.female').hide();
    } else {
      $('.male').hide();
      $('.female').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li class="input-container">
    <input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_1" value="Female" type="radio">
    <label for="3151_55396_8_60103_1">Female</label>
  </li>
  <li class="input-container">
    <input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_2" value="Male" type="radio">
    <label for="3151_55396_8_60103_2">Male</label>
  </li>
</ul>

<select class="female" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Female - Small">Female - Small</option>
<option value="Female - Medium">Female - Medium</option>
<option value="Female - Large">Female - Large</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="male" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Male - Small">Male - Small</option>
<option value="Male - Medium">Male - Medium</option>
<option value="Male - Large">Male - Large</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!. I will accept the answer as soon as it allows me to. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the .attr(...) method, and check if the "checked" attribute is there (if not checked, it will be undefined, and return false in the if statement).

```
if( $('input[value=Female]').attr('checked')){
    ...
} ...
```

Here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/uf6q6csq/1/

Answer (score 0):

You replace `$('input[value=Female]').is('checked')` 
by  `$(this).val()=='Female'` and do the same to rest one

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
  
   if( $(this).val()=='Female' ) {
     $('.female').show();
    $('.male').hide();
   } else if($(this).val()=='Male' ) {
    $('.male').show();
    $('.female').hide();
   } else {
     $('.male').hide();
    $('.female').hide();
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

<li class="input-container">
<input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_1" value="Female" type="radio">
<label for="3151_55396_8_60103_1">Female</label>
</li>
<li class="input-container">
<input class="testtesttest" name="3151_55396_8_60103" id="3151_55396_8_60103_2" value="Male" type="radio">
<label for="3151_55396_8_60103_2">Male</label>
</li>
</ul>

<select class="female" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Female - Small">Female - Small</option>
<option value="Female - Medium">Female - Medium</option>
<option value="Female - Large">Female - Large</option>
</select>
<br />
<select class="male" name="3151_55396_9_60104" id="3151_55396_9_60104" onchange="choiceSelected('3151_55396_9_60104', this.selectedIndex);">

<option value="NOREPLY">Please select response</option>
<option value="Male - Small">Male - Small</option>
<option value="Male - Medium">Male - Medium</option>
<option value="Male - Large">Male - Large</option>
</select>
```